# What is the most idiomatic verb to use with ‘reading’?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, idioms

In the following sentence, by ‘reading’ I mean ‘study’ or ‘research’. What is the best verb to use with it?

I —————— an ecological reading of the Japanese literary tradition.

Do, conduct, carry out, make (?) come to my mind, but I don’t know which one is the right word.

Comment: I do some ecological reading of .....

Comment: _am doing_, perhaps.

Comment: It's not clear that "reading" is the best term here.

Comment: @HotLicks It is. *Reading* is academic jargon for textual analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conduct** is fine; other verbs are possible depending on context.

Your usage of *reading* is accepted jargon within literary criticism. It generally means an analysis of one or several texts, or an analysis of a phenomenon using texts. (See *close reading*  [[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close%20reading), which has led to analyses based in other theories,e.g. [feminist reading](https://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=%22feminist%20reading%22), [deconstructive reading](https://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=%22deconstructive%20reading%22), and [ecological reading](https://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=%22ecological%20reading%22).)

In my experience, verbs that would be used with *an analysis* would also work well for doing a reading, like *conduct*. A verb-based collocation search with "analysis" in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) confirms this hunch; the top results are

- *perform* and *performed* (111 and 96 results)
- *conduct* and *conducted* (84 and 95 results)

Indeed, in searching for actual usages with *reading*, *conduct* and other verbs are used:

> How do we **conduct an ecological reading** of premodern cultures without being merely presentist, polemical, or romanticist? (*[Ritual Dynamics in Jewish and Christian Contexts: Between Bible and Liturgy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ritual_Dynamics_in_Jewish_and_Christian/ysuiDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22conduct%20an%20ecological%20reading%22&pg=PA215&printsec=frontcover)*)

> Ruth Mas **conducts a close reading** of the concept of translation itself, as Mandir develops it mainly in relation to Derrida and to Nakoi Sakai, who develops his idea of co-configuration in relation to Kant's idea of schematism ("[The Past Future of Postcolonial 'Category' Religion, Theory, and Translation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23555761)")

> The data of biblical theology, in both the Old and New Testaments, allow us - if they do not indubitably require us - **to develop an ecological reading** of biblical faith, focusing on the themes now familiar to us, especially in the works of Irenaeus and Augustine, as integrating constructs: the land of promise and the fecundity of God. (*[The Travail of Nature: The Ambiguous Ecological Promise of Christian Theology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Travail_of_Nature/zIfWQF4BmggC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22an%20ecological%20reading%22&pg=PA189&printsec=frontcover)*)

> In one of these assignments, students **perform a close reading** of passages from *Orientalism* (Said 1978) [...] ("[Rethinking Combined Departments: An Argument for History and Anthropology](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24718031)")